# Efficient Management of dictionaries and clearing depreciated data

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm developing a real-time object tracking system in Python, focusing on detecting objects, tracking their movements, and analyzing their states (e.g., crossing lines, entering defined areas). My system's state is managed through several dictionaries, each serving a different purpose:

1. `crossed_track_ids`: Tracks objects that have crossed a predefined line.
2. `inside_square`: A `defaultdict` indicating whether an object is inside a specific square area.
3. `track_history`: A `defaultdict` of `deque`s, storing the last two positions of each tracked object to analyze movement.

I'm encountering challenges in maintaining these dictionaries efficiently, especially ensuring they only contain entries for currently active tracked objects. Here's a simplified version of how I'm using these dictionaries:

```py
from collections import defaultdict, deque

# Placeholder for actual functions
def segment_intersection(...):
    pass

def has_crossed_line(track_id, line_start, line_end):
    pass

def is_within_square(track_id, square_corners):
    pass

# Dictionaries for tracking
crossed_track_ids = {}
inside_square = defaultdict(bool)
track_history = defaultdict(lambda: deque(maxlen=2))

def process_detections(detections):
    global crossed_track_ids, inside_square, track_history
    active_track_ids = [detection.track_id for detection in detections]

    for detection in detections:
        track_id = detection.track_id
        position = (detection.x, detection.y)  # Simplified for example
        
        track_history[track_id].append(position)
        
        if has_crossed_line(track_id, line_start, line_end):
            crossed_track_ids[track_id] = True
        inside_square[track_id] = is_within_square(track_id, square_corners)

    # Challenge: Need an efficient method to remove entries for inactive tracks.

# Example call to process detections
process_detections(detections)
```

**My Challenge:** I'm seeking an efficient way to manage these dictionaries, ensuring they are pruned of entries relating to inactive track IDs without incurring significant processing overhead. My goal is to maintain performance and avoid memory bloat as the number of tracked objects grows and some become inactive over time.

**Question:** What are the best practices or patterns for dynamically managing such dictionaries in a real-time context? Specifically, how can I ensure these structures only reference active track IDs, efficiently removing or ignoring inactive ones? Is there a more effective approach than periodically checking and cleaning these dictionaries based on activity status?

Any advice or insight into structuring this aspect of my system for optimal performance and scalability would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider using the `weakref` library. Inactive keys that are not used anywhere else will become garbage automatically.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the suggestion. Is this an efficient solution? Considering my api is bring called about 30 times a second

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please review the rules and guidelines before asking a question.  In particular, questions soliciting opinions, such as what are "best practices" are considered off topic https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic

Comment: @possum thanks for your feedback but am I soliciting an opinion? Because I find this to be a blocker on how to clear multiple indicative dictionaries while looping through another one.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be efficient. It's tied directly into the garbage collector's algorithm.

Comment: Awesome! @Barmar. you can put that as an answer and il vote it